# Tomcat logging configuration

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7 / 8 in cloud, in panel log viewer got below log files:
Log files

1. Catalina.out
2. instance.log
3. access log

And i found official document from tomcat, but still confused.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

I cannot access such folder like /apache/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/logs
Can explain the usage for each log file with sample words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words:

1. Catalina.out - Some app logs and system specific logs
2. instance.log - Application specific logs
3. access log - Contains the app paths that were accessed (the users' Web requests)

**More details / bg:**

1. Catalina.out : "When running Tomcat on unixes, the console output is usually redirected to the file named catalina.out", so your System.out.println, logger.info, or exception should be found in it.
2. instance.log : the log related to application running status / life cycle.
3. There are two main approaches to configure Tomcat logs:

   a. The java.util.logging (JUL) API

   found at `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties`

   b. Apache log4j

   found at `$CATALINA_BASE/lib/log4j.properties`. Don't confuse this with application's logs.

`log4j.jar` and `log4j.properties` go into `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/classes`, respectively, in your web application.